# Replace a word in a string with a styled span dynamically

Tags: javascript, html, css, dynamic

I'm trying to do something pretty simple, but I'm embarrassed to say that I can't figure it out. I'm looking to find words in a string that start with '@' or '#' and give the word a styling color of blue. The string is coming from an API, so I can't initially set the word inside a span.

I've tried used string `replace()` with a regular expression to find words that start with '@', and replace it with a span that has the same text, but with the color blue. I've seen this answer pop up throughout SO, but when I try to implement it the entire span is rendered as text, instead of just the text itself. Moreover, the text doesn't have the color changed to blue– I'm getting `<span style='color: blue;'>@user42</span>` as text, instead of just `@user42`.

I used a different regexp to remove the spans from being rendered to the page as text but that just seems like I missing something and doing extra work to remedy what I'm unaware of.

Here's what I've tried to do to solve it without using `.replace()`, but I'm unable to insert the newly created span into the same position as the word being removed.

```js
tweetText[0].split(' ').forEach((word) => {
  if (word.innerText.startsWith('@') || word.innerText.startsWith('#')) {
     const span = document.createElement('span');
     span.innerText = word;
     span.style.color = 'blue';
   }
 });
```

How can I use `replace()` to find a word that starts with '@' or '#' and replace it with the same text, but with a different color?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Added color, background-color, padding, and border-radius to look good.

```js
const result = document.querySelector(".result");

function colorizeSelectedText(str) {
  const result = str
    .split(" ")
    .map((word) => {
      if (word.startsWith("@") || word.startsWith("#")) {
        return `<span style='color: blue; background: bisque; padding: 0.25rem; border-radius: 4px;'>${word}</span>`;
      }
      return word;
    })
    .join(" ");
  return result;
}

const text = colorizeSelectedText(
  "This is @test for the #color that is not colored"
);

result.innerHTML = text;
```

```html
<div class="result"></div>
```

Comment: thank you for the help. Really appreciate it. It solved my issue. I still have a lot to learn about javascript and coding, in general. Take care.

Comment: Glad I could help you. 